# how to link a the contact form of my website to my mail using javamail

Tags: java, html, email, servlets, jakarta-mail

hi i have a contact form in my website with field name, user email ,user password ,content and submit button. If they give submit button i should get mail in my inbox with their email and content. I have searched many article in every article they are getting admin mail and admin password but my need is to get a mail from the website user with their mail id

Comment: means with user mail id which in contact form and without authentication you want.

Comment: If george is the user he going to my  form and want to send some content to my mail id (admin@ab.com) . so the george will type his name and email id and content and click send button .     now in my inbox(admin@ab.com) i should get the mail from george@ab.com with his content

Comment: If you have password of george@ab.com then we can send a java mail with this mail id and password. We must have sender mail id with password for authentication to send a mail. Without authentication in `java` its not possible i think so.

Comment: In `php` we can can send a mail without authentication means by using only mail id without password. But sometimes it will goes to `spam`.

Comment: the user only going to send the mail so we can have an extra field called password then in the website the user will enter the mail with password and feedback and click submit then the admin can able to get a mail @satya

Comment: So its easy, use java mail to send mail with user's mail id and password. As part of body send the content.

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You should reconsider whether this is the best approach to your problem.

To use JavaMail to send the message based on information in the web form, you're going to have to ask the user for all the configuration information needed to access their mail server - host name, port name, ssl or not, user name, and most importantly password.  Users might not know all that information, and might not be willing to give you their email password.

Even if you got all that information, you might not be able to access the user's email server if you're not on the user's network.

If you just want the user to send you a message, you could just use a mailto: link in your web page with your email address.  The user would then use their own mail program, already properly configured, to send you a message.  Although even that might not work if the user is using only a web mail user interface.

Why do you need the user to send mail directly from their own account?

Comment: hi @Bill Shannon i need a mail from the user of my website which they commented in the text area of my website

Comment: Why do you need them to send you a message in order to get their email address?

Comment: okay thank you for your valuable advice